# jQuery: Check to see if table row containing certain values exists already

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery script that appends a row to a table. In short, the user can select a value from a drop down menu, then enter in 'x' amount of months and hits 'add', which appends the row to the table.  For example the following row is appended by the user:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Some Value</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

Now, if the user performs the same operation again, I need to stop the procedure and alert him that he is trying to add a duplicate value. How - using jQuery - can I check to see whether or not the above row already exists, where the first and second `<td>` elements have the same value as the data he is trying to add? The reason I say first and second `<td>` elements only is because there are other `<td>` elements in the row but they house hidden fields which submit the newly added data to to a server side script, so I'd like to keep the validation as short and simple as possible.

If it is of any help, the table ID is `#tblspecializations`

Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might be able to use [*:contains()*](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('#tblspecializations tr > td:contains(Some Value) + td:contains(2)').length
```

- [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4W92A/)

Be aware, though, that *:contains()* will return the element if the given string is matched anywhere in the text of the element.

Comment: Worked like a BOMB, many thanks indeed. I am not too concerned about the values being similar as they are predefined values anyway. I simple added the following function and all worked great:

  if($('#tblspecialization td:contains('+$slabel+')').length){
   alert('A specialization of the same type and months has already been entered.');
   return false;
  }

Big up to you for your help

Comment: 1+ to you for your help and time and simple effective answer

Comment: +1 for a nice and short solution, and for teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you hold your data in some data structure (an (associative) array for example). Thus you will verify the data in the structure, rather than in the DOM.

Comment: I really like this approach and am sure it is better practice, but for this scenario all the code is structured in a certain manner already, albeit not the best manner, I needed a solution I could simply 'plug in' to the current logic. Many thanks for your guidance though! Much appreciated

Comment: 1+ to you for your help and time

Answer (score 2):

To put it short, the following code in the `click()` handler should help you in your situation; you can [see the whole code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/2CVnn/):

```
$(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var table = $("#tblspecializations");
        var firstTd = $("td:first", table);
        var secondTd = firstTd.next();

        if(firstTd.text() == $("#dropdown").val() && secondTd.text() == $("#num").val())
            alert("Error: You're trying to add the same entry");
    });
});
```

Short explanation: By using `td:first` in the selector, you're getting the first column in your table, and by using the `next()` function, your getting its sibling, namely the second column.

Comment: this also works for me, however I found Andy E's answer to be the shortest solution. Thank you for your time though! It does not go unnoticed.

Comment: 1+ for you for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

if($('table').find('td').filter(function () {return this.innerHTML == '20';}).length>0){ alert("Si");}else{alert("No");}