# Determine whether an exact row exists in an html table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want the same as the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657885/jquery-check-to-see-if-table-row-containing-certain-values-exists-already) but to determine whether a row actually exists in a table.  I.e. I do not want to know whether a value exists in a table but I want to know whether the exact row (`<tr ....></tr>`) already exists.

Any ideas :)?

Comment: How did the data get there in the first place?  The solution may be better located elsewhere...  for example, querying the database where it came from.

Comment: Does the <tr> have a hook such as a className, ID, etc?

Comment: what do you mean by exact row. do you have html of a row and you want to know if the html is contained in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need just to check if table contains a specific row you could do like this:

```
if($("#rowID").length){
   //Horray you have the row you specified.
}
else{
   //what you should do when the row doesn't exist
}
```

Note that `if($("#rowID").length)` implies that length of the element not equal zero which means that it exists, you can also change the way you want to select the element with you could do something like that `$("#tableID tr").length`.

I hope this could help you

Answer (score 1):

> it so simple just check in html of table.

```
if($("#tbodyAvailableRooms").html()==""){
     //Dose not exist row in HTML Table
}
else
{
    //Dose not exist row in HTML Table
}
```